# VueJS <v-select> doesn't bind when posting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, select, vue.js, vuejs2

I am developing an asp.net mvc application using VueJS on the front end. I have a bunch of forms and while text field works fine when submitting the form (meaning I can see it binds with the view model and I can see the value typed in on the form) it is not the case with `<v-select>`

Here is what I have:

```
<v-select clearable :items="options" 
                item-text="name"
                label="Months" v-model="Month"></v-select>
```

I would expect it would bind with `myViewModel.Month` but it doesn't.

I can bind the `v-select` with a hidden field and the value of hidden field will bind with my viewmodel but that's an extra step (and element).

I am new to VueJS so if anyone can give me some pointers. Thank you.

Updates:

My code looks like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EOzrgV

And the question not about model binding within Vue but model binding with my C# ViewModel. So for example I have the following controller:

```
    public ActionResult Member()
    {
        if (!LoggedIn)
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        MemberViewModel model = new MemberViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Member(MemberViewModel model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Here I can see value of model.name
            // But model.month is always empty
            //model.Save();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us your JS like the data() { part atleast }

Comment: Added to the original post above.

Comment: Is that your backend app is just an API ? I think you need to send manually these data to you C# controller

Comment: Hi @Jérôme it is a backend app. The binding issue is only on `v-select` I don't have to do anything special with `v-text-field`. Assigning name property the same as the property name of my view model does what I expect to do.

Answer (score 2):

If your data object is looking like

```
data: {
  myViewModel: {
    Month: '',
  },  
}
```

You need to need to bind it like `myViewModel.Month`

```
<v-select clearable
  :items="options" 
  item-text="name"
  label="Months"
  v-model="myViewModel.Month"
></v-select>
```

I made a example here: https://jsfiddle.net/kIINAMITE/eywraw8t/491056/

Comment: It is the binding with C# view model that I have trouble with. Thanks.